# MAVProxy Connect 0.0.0.0:14550

Tags: python, python-3.x, connection

I'm trying to connect Misson Planner so that I can simulate, but getting this error:

```
(proje) C:\Users\hasan>mavproxy.py --master tcp:127.0.0.1:5760 --out udp:127.0.0.1:20000 --out udp:127.0.0.1:10000
Auto-detected serial ports are:
Connect 0.0.0.0:14550 source_system=255
Loaded module console
Log Directory:
Telemetry log: mav.tlog
Waiting for heartbeat from 0.0.0.0:14550
MAV>
```

The IP i want to connect to is 127.0.0.1 but it tries to connect 0.0.0.0:14550. I did some research but none of the solutions i found solved my problem.

MAVProxy version = 1.8.35
pymavlink version = 2.4.8

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Fsa9.png)